# How can I split a column in a specific range?

Tags: python, r, bash, file, shell

I'm working with proteins trajectory and I've got a long data frame. (File with one column and 600.000 lines.

This is and example:

```
100
100
0
100
100
...
n=600.000
```

What I wish is to split this data every 3000 lines, creating a new column beside like this example:

```
Col1     Col2     Col3     Col4      Col...200:
n=1      n=3001   n=6001   n=9001    ...
0        0        0        0         ...
0        0        0        0         ...
100      100      100      100       ...
...      ...      ...      ...       ...
n=3000   n=6000   n=9000   n=12000   n=600.000
```

n= line number.

Is there any way to do this in **R or bash**?

Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT: I'm using this script in python to generate that column:

```
    from decimal import *
i = 1
while(i <= 15):
    output = open('cache/distances_'+str(i)+'.dat.results', 'w') 
    with open('cache/distances_medias_'+str(i)+'.dat', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            columns = line.split(' ')
            if(Decimal(columns[0]) <= 2.5 and (Decimal(columnas[1]) > 120 and Decimal(columnas[1]) < 180)):
                salida.write("100\n")
            else:
                salida.write("0\n")
    salida.close()
    i+=2
```

Is there any way to modify the script and when it reaches the line 3000,  start in a new column?

Comment: It is hard, because you probably have to read all the file in memory and then keep printing on a second read.

Comment: the example you posted is not clear. The first two rows of the example are "100", but the "Col1" of the output starts with two "0". Moreover it is not clear if "n=1" should appear in the output or it is just an example.

Comment: @fedorqui I added the script in python that I use to generate that column. Maybe there's some way to modify the script and separate each 3000 lines.

Comment: First `split -l 3000` to split the big file in seperate files and past them together with `paste` (BASH)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -v n=5 '{data[(NR-1)%n FS int((NR-1)/n)]=$0}
            END {cols=NR/n;
            for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
                 for (j=0;j<cols;j++) 
                      printf "%s%s", data[i FS j], FS} 
                 print ""
                 }
            }'
```

That is: store all the content in a kind-of matrix and then loop accordingly.

#### Sample outputs

```
$ seq 15 | awk -v n=3 '{data[(NR-1)%n FS int((NR-1)/n)]=$0} END {cols=NR/n; for (i=0;i<n;i++) {for (j=0;j<cols;j++) {printf "%s%s", data[i FS j], FS} print ""}}'
1 4 7 10 13 
2 5 8 11 14 
3 6 9 12 15 
$ seq 15 | awk -v n=7 '{data[(NR-1)%n FS int((NR-1)/n)]=$0} END {cols=NR/n; for (i=0;i<n;i++) {for (j=0;j<cols;j++) {printf "%s%s", data[i FS j], FS} print ""}}'
1 8 15 
2 9  
3 10  
4 11  
5 12  
6 13  
7 14  
$ seq 15 | awk -v n=5 '{data[(NR-1)%n FS int((NR-1)/n)]=$0} END {cols=NR/n; for (i=0;i<n;i++) {for (j=0;j<cols;j++) {printf "%s%s", data[i FS j], FS} print ""}}'
1 6 11 
2 7 12 
3 8 13 
4 9 14 
5 10 15
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure I understand your example, but you should be able to use a combination of split and paste:

```
$ cat filetosplit
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

$ split filetosplit  "split." -l 3 -d ; paste split*
1       4       7       10
2       5       8
3       6       9
```

The split command will generate files for 3 lines per row (you can modify to 3000). The paste will put all them together. You can use sed to add an header with column names and initial number.

Comment: Very interesting! You may want to remove the split* files afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

In R you may just may add a `dim` attribute:

```
dim(your_vector) <- c(3000, 600000/3000)
```

It will change an object class to `matrix`, so if you need data frame, you will need:

```
df <- data.frame(your_vector)
```